# Storing course records from a CSV file, structures not storing properly

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, structure, allocation

So I have this program that is supposed to take in a CSV file for reading input, given as such.

**CSV:**

```
programming, 03, 60, 141, 1, 30, 0, W, 2015

algebra, 03, 62, 102, 2, 0, 0, S, 2013

religion, 08, 98, 938, 1, 30, 90, W, 2015
```

We're supposed to read into our structure and from there a `switch/case` menu will open up allowing you to add course data, search for a course and display the course in a table. Right now I'm having an issue storing each of the read inputs into its given structure variables.

I have assigned `char []` values to store the values for now and as you can see I print them off right after I obtain them. The problem is when I try to use the `strcpy()` function to load each of the given variables into the `struct`, the string values do not copy over. I've tried looking at multiple different examples and feel like I'm at a dead end. I've used this logic before in a different program. The big difference I guess is the buff `char` pointer having a `malloc` of size `struct`. As of right now, the `courseID` and the `courseSections` are only printing out which is what leads me to believe this is an issue with storing the strings. I don't know how to approach this problem at the moment.

```
//Assignment 3
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define filename "courseInfo.csv"

struct CourseInfo{
    int courseID;
    char courseName[40];
    char courseCode[10];
    char Term [6];
    int courseSections[3];
};

typedef struct CourseInfo courseInfo; //optional
courseInfo courseList[3];

void loadCourseInfo() //To read all data from the input file (courseInfo.csv) and format and store
//them in an array of strutcures
{
/* FileStream for the Library File */
    FILE *fptr;

    /* allocation of the buffer for every line in the File */
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(courseInfo) + 1);
    char *tmp; 

    /* if the space could not be allocaed, return an error */
    if (buf == NULL) {
        printf ("No memory\n");
    }

    if ( ( fptr = fopen(filename, "r" ) ) == NULL ) //Reading a file
    {
        printf( "File could not be opened.\n" );
    }

    int i = 0;
    char nameX[40];

    char facX[2];
    char subX[2];
    char levX[3];

    int sec1, sec2, sec3;
    char semX[1];
    char yearX[4];

    //char courseCodeX[10];
    //char TermX[6];
    while (fgets(buf, 100, fptr) != NULL)
    {
        tmp = strtok(buf, ",");
        strcpy(nameX, tmp);
        printf("%s ", nameX);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
        strcpy(facX, tmp);
        printf("%s ", facX);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
        strcpy(subX, tmp);
        printf("%s ", subX);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
        strcpy(levX, tmp);
        printf("%s ", levX);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
        sec1 = atoi(tmp);
        printf("%i ", sec1);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
        sec2 = atoi(tmp);
        printf("%i ", sec2);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
        sec3 = atoi(tmp);
        printf("%i ", sec3);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
        strcpy(semX, tmp);
        printf("%s ", semX);

        tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
        strcpy(yearX, tmp);
        printf("%s ", yearX);
        printf("\n");

        //strcat(courseCodeX, facX);
        //strcat(courseCodeX, subX);
        //strcat(courseCodeX, "-");
        //strcat(courseCodeX, levX);
        //printf("%s ", courseCodeX);

        //strcat(TermX, semX);
        //strcat(TermX, yearX);
        //printf("%s ", TermX);

        courseList[i].courseID = i + 1;
        strcpy(courseList[i].courseName, nameX);
        strcpy(courseList[i].courseCode, facX);
        strcpy(courseList[i].Term, semX);
        courseList[i].courseSections[0] = sec1;
        courseList[i].courseSections[1] = sec2;
        courseList[i].courseSections[2] = sec3;     

        i++;
    }
    //free(buf);
    fclose(fptr);
}

/*void addCourseInfo(courseInfo courseList, int arraySize)To add a new course
a) CourseID should be unique and generated automatically by your program (last courseID + 1)
b) CourseCode is also unique and you can't have 2 courses with the same courCode. So before
adding a course, search for the courseCode to be sure that you have not had it previously
c) Number of sections cannot be more than 3. Also, sections numbers for each course must be unique
{
    courseInfo tempcourse[arraySize + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        strcpy(tempcourse[i].courseName, courseList[i].courseName);

        strcpy(tempcourse[i].faculty, courseList[i].faculty);
        strcpy(tempcourse[i].subject, courseList[i].subject);
        strcpy(tempcourse[i].level, courseList[i].level);
        strcpy(tempcourse[i].courseCode,  courseList[i].courseCode);

        strcpy(tempcourse[i].semester, courseList[i].semester);
        strcpy(tempcourse[i].year, courseList[i].year);     
        strcpy(tempcourse[i].Term,  courseList[i].Term);

        tempcourse[i].sections[0] = courseList[i].sections[0];
        tempcourse[i].sections[1] = courseList[i].sections[1];
        tempcourse[i].sections[2] = courseList[i].sections[2];

        tempcourse[i].courseID = courseList[i].courseID;
    }

    printf("Enter course name: ");
    scanf("%s", tempcourse[arraySize].courseName);

    printf("\nEnter  faculty code (format xx): ");
    scanf("%s", tempcourse[arraySize].faculty);

    printf("\nEnter subject code (format xx): ");
    scanf("%s", tempcourse[arraySize].subject);

    printf("\nEnter level code (format xx): ");
    scanf("%s", tempcourse[arraySize].level);
    //This is where you need to put all three of the above together
    //complete a strcmp throughout all the current records of temp course
    //maybe call that in a separate function and return that in main somehow

    int section;
    printf("\nEnter number of sections: ");
    scanf("%i", &section);
    if(section < 1 && section > 3)
    {
        printf("Invalid Input!\n");
        printf("Enter number of sections: ");
        scanf("%i", &section);
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            printf("\nEnter section code %i:". i + 1);
            scanf("%s", tempcourse[arraySize].section[i]);
            if(tempcourse[arraySize].section[i] == tempcourse[arraySize].section[i - 1]);
            {
                printf("Invalid: Repeated section code!\n");
                printf("Enter section code %i:". i);//KEEP AN EYE OUT FOR THIS BUGGER
                scanf("%s", tempcourse[arraySize].section[i]);
            }               
        }
    }

    printf("\nEnter semester (S, F, or W): ");
    scanf("%c", tempcourse[arraySize].semester);

    printf("\nEnter year (format yyyy): ");
    scanf("%s", tempcourse[arraySize].year);

    printf("Course Added Succesfully!");

}
*/
void displayCourseInfo() //Print a table indicating course information
{
    printf("ID   Name           Code      Term      Sections\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%i %s %s %s %i,%i,%i \n", courseList[i].courseID, courseList[i].courseName, courseList[i].courseCode, courseList[i].Term, courseList[i].courseSections[0], courseList[i].courseSections[1], courseList[i].courseSections[2]);
    }
}
/*
searchCourseID() //To search a course information using courseID and print the course information
//if the course information exists

searchCourseName()//Search for course information using courseName and print the course information
//if it the course infoamtion exists

searchCourseTerm()//Search ALL course information using Term (semester and year) and print the list
//of all course information if it exists

saveCourseInfo() //To save course information from the array of structures to a CSV file (courseInfo.csv)
*/
void switchCaseMenu(int selection)
{
    int menuActive = 1;
    while(menuActive)
    {

        printf("Assignment 3\n");
        printf("------------\n");
        printf("1. Add a new course\n");
        printf("2. Seearch for a course ID\n");
        printf("3. Search for a course by course Name\n");
        printf("4. Search for all courses by term\n");
        printf("5. Display course data\n");
        printf("6. Save course data\n");
        printf("7. Exit\n");

        printf("Please enter a selection: ");
        scanf("%i", &selection);

        switch(selection)
        {
            case 7:
                menuActive = 0;
                break;
            case 6:
                printf("Selecteed - Save Course Data\n");

                break;
            case 5:
                printf("Selected - Display Course Data\n");
                displayCourseInfo();

                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Selected - Searfh for All Courses By Term\n");

                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Selected - Search for Course by Course Name\n");

                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Selected - Search for Course ID\n");

                break;
            case 1:
                printf("Selected - Add a New Course\n");
                //addCourseInfo(courseInfo, );

                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid Input!\n");
        }
    }
    printf("You Have Quit!\n");

}

int main()
{   
    loadCourseInfo();

    int select = 0;
    switchCaseMenu(select);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @user3121023 So instead of using strtok function to split each string at the comma delimiter, i use the sscanf function like how you've shown. Would I use that in conjunction with fgets in the while loop or would would it replace that entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sscanf` the function would look something like this.

```
void loadCourseInfo() //To read all data from the input file (courseInfo.csv) and format and store
//them in an array of strutcures
{
    /* FileStream for the Library File */
    FILE *fptr;
    char buf[100] = "";

    if ( ( fptr = fopen(filename, "r" ) ) == NULL ) //Reading a file
    {
        printf( "File could not be opened.\n" );
        return;
    }

    int i = 0;
    char nameX[40];

    char facX[3];
    char subX[3];
    char levX[4];

    int sec1, sec2, sec3;
    char semX[2];
    char yearX[6];

    while ( i < 3 && fgets(buf, 100, fptr) != NULL)
    {
        if ( 9 == sscanf ( buf, " %39[^,], %2[^,], %2[^,], %3[^,], %d, %d, %d, %1[^,], %4s"
        , nameX, facX, subX, levX, &sec1, &sec2, &sec3, semX, yearX)) { 
            printf("%s ", nameX);
            printf("%s ", facX);
            printf("%s ", subX);
            printf("%s ", levX);
            printf("%d ", sec1);
            printf("%d ", sec2);
            printf("%d ", sec3);
            printf("%s ", semX);
            printf("%s ", yearX);
            printf("\n");

            courseList[i].courseID = i + 1;
            strcpy(courseList[i].courseName, nameX);
            strcpy(courseList[i].courseCode, facX);
            strcpy(courseList[i].Term, semX);
            courseList[i].courseSections[0] = sec1;
            courseList[i].courseSections[1] = sec2;
            courseList[i].courseSections[2] = sec3;     

            i++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

This may not address all the problems.

This works as far as it goes...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define filename "courseInfo.csv"

struct CourseInfo{
    int courseID;
    char courseName[40];
    char courseCode[10];
    char Term [6];
    int courseSections[3];
};

typedef struct CourseInfo courseInfo; //optional
courseInfo courseList[3];

void loadCourseInfo() //To read all data from the input file (courseInfo.csv) and format and store
//them in an array of strutcures
{
    /* FileStream for the Library File */
    FILE *fptr;
    char buf[100] = "";
    char courseCodeX[10];
    char TermX[6];

    if ( ( fptr = fopen(filename, "r" ) ) == NULL ) //Reading a file
    {
        printf( "File could not be opened.\n" );
        return;
    }

    int i = 0;
    char nameX[40];

    char facX[3];
    char subX[3];
    char levX[4];

    int sec1, sec2, sec3;
    char semX[2];
    char yearX[6];

    while ( i < 3 && fgets(buf, 100, fptr) != NULL)
    {
        if ( 9 == sscanf ( buf, " %39[^,], %2[^,], %2[^,], %3[^,], %d, %d, %d, %1[^,], %4s"
        , nameX, facX, subX, levX, &sec1, &sec2, &sec3, semX, yearX)) {
            printf("%s ", nameX);
            printf("%s ", facX);
            printf("%s ", subX);
            printf("%s ", levX);
            printf("%d ", sec1);
            printf("%d ", sec2);
            printf("%d ", sec3);
            printf("%s ", semX);
            printf("%s ", yearX);
            printf("\n");

            strcpy(courseCodeX, facX);
            strcat(courseCodeX, subX);
            strcat(courseCodeX, "-");
            strcat(courseCodeX, levX);
            printf("%s\n", courseCodeX);

            strcpy(TermX, semX);
            strcat(TermX, yearX);
            printf("%s\n", TermX);

            courseList[i].courseID = i + 1;
            strcpy(courseList[i].courseName, nameX);
            strcpy(courseList[i].courseCode, facX);
            strcpy(courseList[i].Term, semX);
            courseList[i].courseSections[0] = sec1;
            courseList[i].courseSections[1] = sec2;
            courseList[i].courseSections[2] = sec3;

            i++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}

void displayCourseInfo() //Print a table indicating course information
{
    printf("ID                          Name           Code  Term Sections\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%2d %39s %3s %4s  %2d,%2d,%2d \n", courseList[i].courseID, courseList[i].courseName, courseList[i].courseCode, courseList[i].Term, courseList[i].courseSections[0], courseList[i].courseSections[1], courseList[i].courseSections[2]);
    }
}

void switchCaseMenu(int selection)
{
    int menuActive = 1;
    while(menuActive)
    {

        printf("Assignment 3\n");
        printf("------------\n");
        printf("1. Add a new course\n");
        printf("2. Seearch for a course ID\n");
        printf("3. Search for a course by course Name\n");
        printf("4. Search for all courses by term\n");
        printf("5. Display course data\n");
        printf("6. Save course data\n");
        printf("7. Exit\n");

        printf("Please enter a selection: ");
        scanf("%i", &selection);

        switch(selection)
        {
            case 7:
                menuActive = 0;
                break;
            case 6:
                printf("Selecteed - Save Course Data\n");

                break;
            case 5:
                printf("Selected - Display Course Data\n");
                displayCourseInfo();

                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Selected - Searfh for All Courses By Term\n");

                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Selected - Search for Course by Course Name\n");

                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Selected - Search for Course ID\n");

                break;
            case 1:
                printf("Selected - Add a New Course\n");
                //addCourseInfo(courseInfo, );

                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid Input!\n");
        }
    }
    printf("You Have Quit!\n");

}

int main()
{
    loadCourseInfo();

    int select = 0;
    switchCaseMenu(select);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I definitely had my code wrong earlier. The basic gist is that i usedfacX, subX, levX,  somehow cacatenate them altogether and assign it to courseCode[10] using strcpy. Same idea with semX and yearX into Term[6]. As of this moment I implement the given function but it looks like the program terminates after this function. My switch case menu is not accessible and by using some printf statements found out nothing happens after fclose.